# shortest tree path vertex

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

We have a directed graph G(V, E) with positive weights on the edges, as source vertex s and a destination t. Also, the shortest s − t path includes every other vertex in the graph.
I need to compute alternate shortest path distances between s and t in case some edge e ∈ E is removed. I want to design an **O(E^2 log V)** algorithm that computes, for all e ∈ E, the shortest s − t path distance in the graph G \ e. The final output should be an array of size E where the entry for edge e should contain the shortest s − t path distance in G \ e.

Comment: This sounds like a homework exercise, so here's a hint: Before looking for an algorithm, try to prove that in any graph formed by deleting some edge on this "backbone" shortest s-t path, there is a shortest s-t path with a simple structure.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Unless specified elsewhere in the problem, there is no guarantee that removing an edge will keep the graph connected and a path s-t still exists (just think of the simplest possible graph where edges and vertices are the ones included in the original s-t).

Comment: @Rocco: Right, I should have made explicit my assumption that a solution exists. I think this is probably granted in the problem statement, but in any case, all bridges (edges whose deletion would disconnect the graph) can be found in O(|E|) time -- if any edge on the "backbone" s-t path is a bridge, then there is no solution for that edge, so solve 2 components that remain as separate subproblems.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, the only relevant case is when the removed edge is part of the backbone (if not, s-t  doesn't change) and at least one edge from any node before the break to any other node after the break exists (as you said, no solution otherwise), so now the OP has enough information for the solution.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Can you please explain what you mean by "simple structure".

Comment: I mean you don't have to start looking for a shortest path completely from scratch, because there must exist a shortest path that is "like" the path you already had (in some specific sense) and it's enough to find that path.

Comment: @j_random_hackerYes I understand that the main key to this question is finding that relation/overlap between the initial shortest path and the new shortest path after removing a particular edge. But I am not able to figure out what special about this overlap? Does the new path also pass through each node? Does the new path pass through vertices in the exact same order?

Comment: @Rocco Can you please please write a more elaborate answer? I am a college student and I am really not able to figure out the solution.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ok, I created an answer, please check it, and tell me if something doesn't add up. I wrote it in a short time, so no time for review

Answer (score 1):

Consider the S-T path ("backbone" in the following) and number the K vertices in path order, with S as vertex 1.

- S<sub>1</sub> -> V<sub>2</sub> -> ... -> V<sub>K-1</sub> -> T<sub>K</sub>

Define BB<sub>i-j</sub> as the subpath with adjacent vertices from i to j of the original path, including edges in between.

Since all vertices in G belongs to the path, then all edges in G are between two different vertices in the path, name e<sub>i->j</sub> the directed edge from i to j.

Removing an edge from the graph, the only relevant case is when the edge is part of the backbone, in all other case the path does not change.

Removing an edge e<sub>i->j</sub> from the backbone will break it, so only in this case we need to find a replacement, we can demonstrate that the new minimum shortest path has the form

- BB<sub>1-i'</sub> -> e<sub>i'->j'</sub> -> BB<sub>j'-K</sub>   with i'<=i and j'>=j

demonstration left as exercise ;-)

After the replacement the path length is increased by the additional length

- AL(e<sub>i->j</sub>) = weight of e<sub>i->j</sub> - weight of subpath B<sub>i-j</sub>

Our goal is to find a valid replacement edge with the minimum additional cost, here the pseudocode:

```
Glossary:
- v(i) is the i-th vertex in the backbone
- e(i->j) is the edge going out from v(i) to v(j), in the following we only
  consider edges e(i->j) with j>i, i.e. forward edges, singe backward
  edges can never be part of the solution
- e(*->k), k>j is any edge in the BT terminating in v(k) where k is greater
  than j, the first index is unspecified since edges in BT are only sorted
  by destination vertex
- e(*->q), q<j is any edge in the BT terminating in v(q) where q is lower
  than j, the first index is unspecified since edges in BT are only sorted
  by destination vertex
- BT a binary search tree where we store "best" edges found during the
  iteration, the unique key in BT is the destination vertex's index, so
  we can store here at most one incoming edge per vertex, BT is initially
  empty, during the iteration we buld it so that it has the additional
  property that given two edges e(*->a) e(*->b) in BT, if a<b then also
  AL(e(*->a)) < AL(e(*->b)); in fact BT is ordered at same time both
  by destination index and additional length of the edge
  BT invariants (thanks j_random_hacker): at all times, BT contains only edges that
  1. could be used to form a new path if e(i->i+1) is deleted (because they 
     begin at i or before, and end at i+1 or after)
  2. are not dominated by any other such edge. An edge e(i->j) dominates 
     another edge e(i'->j') if both j >= j' and AL(i->j) < AL(i'->j').
     If edge x dominates edge y, it means that, for each edge-deletion yet
     to be considered (e(i->i+1), e(i+1->i+2), etc.), any replacement path 
     that uses y can always be changed to a shorter path using x, so we don't
     need to care about y

//On each iteration we'll search the solution for removal of edge e(i->i+1)
for each vertex v(i) in S-T in path order, excluding T
  //Discard backward edges, since they can only increase the path length
  for each edge e(i->j) going out from v(i) directed to a vertex v(j) with j>i excluding the backbone edge
    calculate additional length AL(e(i->j))
    search BT using j as key, looking for an egde e(*->k) with k >= j
    if such an edge exists and AL(e(*->k)) <= AL(e(i->j))
      discard the current edge (BT's second property requires that)
    else
      //The current edge is the best choice to reach v(j)
      insert edge in BT (if k==j) discard e(*->k)
      //Now me must check if the new edge can also replace previous
      //ones in the BT to keep the second property valiud, for this we have 
      //to scan the BT in descending order and discard edges with AL >= than
      //the current one
      loop over edges e(*->q) in BT with q<j in descending order
        if AL(e(*->q))>=AL(e(i->j))
          discard e(*->q)
        else
          stop loop
      endloop
    end if
  end for each edge
  //Prune tree from useless edges
  remove from BT all edges with j < i+1
  if BT is empty
    no solution
  else
    select the first edge(i'->j') in BT ==> this is the replacement edge with minimum additional cost, so distance is dist(S-T) + AL(e(i'->j'))
end for each vertex
```

Complexity:

- first two loops iterate over all edges, that is O(|E|)
- calculation of al is O(1)
- search in BT, since |BT| <= |V| is O(log |V|) for every iteration
- removing edges from BT, each edge can be inserted and removed only once from the tree so, in total for all iterations, O(|E| log |V|)

In total we have O(|E| log |V|)

Note that the problem does not require to generate the path, but just to calculate the distance, if the path must be generated then the complexity increases, since we can have at most |E| paths of length |V|, then O(|E| |V|)

Comment: You have used a variable k in the pseudo-code, I am assuming k=i+1, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: 2nd Doubt: In the third loop i.e loop over edges in BT with lower j in descending order, what should we do in case when an edge with lower cost is found? I think we should discard the current edge in this case.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson a typo, should be j, im on mobile now, ill fix later. Second doubt, as written in the code an edge with lower cost and index Is the stop condition, buy I should write It better

Comment: Can you please edit the code accordingly? I am not able to understand the significance of the third loop now.

Comment: Also, is tha variable i in the first loop for each vertex v(i) the same as the in in the second loop for each edge e(i->j)? I don't think they should be same. Can you please make the pseudocode a little more understandable and organized?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Added some glossary, fixed typos and reorganized, I think this is the maximum that I can do with pseudocode, hope it's enough

Comment: For each vertex v(i), you are checking only checking the edges e(i->j) i.e you are checking only the edges starting from i . But I think the edge can start from anywhere

Comment: Also in the 2nd loop where you are looking for an egde e(*->k) with k >= j, there is again the possibility that this edge e(*->k) starts after I, i.e *>i

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Edges starting from previous vertices have been checked in previous iterations and the best ones are already stored in BT. And in second loop, all edges in BT come from previous vertices o from the current one, so the start is guaranteed to be <= i.

Comment: You have also taken a search in BT as O(log V ) I don't think that's correct. I have added some additional in the question, please take a look. Also, I just wanted to know if you are not getting bored with this question because I am just doing this question for fun, I found it tricky and intriguing, but If you don't wanna contribute it's alright. Have a nice day!

Comment: @ElliotAlderson BT is a binary  search tree, since it's (unique) key is the destination vertex it can contains at most |V| elements, this is why I assume search, insert and delete operations in BT to be log(|V|), of course I'm not bored otherwise I would not have spent time to write the answer, I did it just because I like it, as you ;-) Unfortunately I didn't had time so far to add some graphics, that would make everything much more understandable.

Comment: There is no need for graphics. I am clearly able to visualize the relation between the new and old shortest path. The thing that's confusing me is the BT, what exactly it stores, how are we filling it. Before the start of any loop, is the BT empty? Also, you said the BT has stored edges in order of additional cost, then how can you search edges based on j. So if you can please throw some light on the BT, it would really help me to understand the code.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson My fault, I wrote that BT is ordered by cost (this was the inital idea when writing), but actually is ordered by edge's destination index and (by construction) also by cost, but the search key is the index; I added the description of BT in the glossary and reviewed the comments on the code for this part.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the meaning of BT is that if I have, for instance, an edge reaching node 5 and it's cost is 4, any edge reaching a lower or equal index with greater cost is useless, since this edge will be still the best choice, while an edge with greater index and greater cost, e.g index 7 cost 6, is useful to reach vertices 6-7, not reached by previous edge. Cost here means additional cost, of course.

Comment: I have changed the question temporarily for a bit. Your answer was correct. Just ignore the new question, please. I repeat, ignore the changes in question.

Comment: BT contains at most |V| elements. But how does that imply that search, insert and delete operations will be O(log(|V|)? In binary search tree, search operation is O(h) where h is height of tree. So the search will be O(|V|) and our final time complexity will be O(|E| |V|)

Comment: Can you please try to fix this? I think maybe using min-heap can help

Comment: @elliotalderson Nope, I mean something likes this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree , self balancing structures with logaritmic access time are readily available in common language. E.g. in Java I should use a TreeSet or TreeMap

Comment: Maybe it helps to mention the BT invariants: At all times, the BT contains only edges that (1) could be used to form a new path if e(i->i+1) is deleted (because they begin at i or before, and end at i+1 or after), and (2) are not dominated by any other such edge. An edge e(i->j) dominates another edge e(i'->j') if both j >= j' and AL(i->j) < AL(i'->j'). If edge x dominates edge y, it means that, for each edge-deletion yet to be considered (e(i->i+1), e(i+1->i+2), etc.), any replacement path that uses y can *always* be changed to a shorter path using x, so we don't need to care about y.

Comment: Thanks @j_random_hacker, I added your comment in the solution